# storing outlook emails to a disk in .MSG format using Java

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail, java

I am using Spring JavaMail API to generate automatic emails to the customers.I am using SMTP server to send this emails.As soon as email goes out to the customer the outgoing email should be stored to some physical location in .MSG format.Is there any java API to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe .MSG is the Microsoft-proprietary file format used by Outlook.  I'm not aware of any Java software that will write that format, but the [Apache POI project](http://poi.apache.org/) can read that format.  Better to store the messages in .EMI format, which is just MIME format.  Or, use your own mail server and store the messages in a folder supported by that mail server.